# How to add argparse flags based on shell find results

Tags: python, shell, argparse

I have a python script that accepts a `-f` flag, and appends multiple uses of the flag.

For example, if I run `python myscript -f file1.txt -f file2.txt`, I would have a list of files, `files=['file1.txt', 'files2.txt']`. This works great, but am wondering how I can automatically use the results of a find command to append as many `-f` flags as there are files.

I've tried:

```
find ./ -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs python myscript.py -f
```

But it only grabs the first file

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to directly search for all filenames within your python script using the [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#module-glob) method?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this from Python, or how to do this from shell?

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that this will fail if there are more files than will fit on a single command line (whereas `xargs` would run `myscript.py` multiple times, each with a subset of the full list of arguments):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do
  args+=( -f "$name" )
done < <(find . -iname '*.txt' -print0)

python myscript.py "${args[@]}"
```

If you want to do this **safely** in a way that tolerates an arbitrary number of filenames, you're better off using a long-form option -- such as `--file` rather than `-f` -- with the `=` separator allowing the individual name to be passed as part of the same argv entry, thus preventing `xargs` from splitting a filename apart from the sigil that precedes it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This requires -printf, a GNU find extension
find . -iname '*.txt' -printf '--file=%p\0' | xargs -0 python myscript.py
```

...or, more portably (running on MacOS, albeit still requiring a shell -- such as bash -- that can handle NUL-delimited reads):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# requires find -print0 and xargs -0; these extensions are available on BSD as well as GNU
find . -iname '*.txt' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do printf '--file=%s\0' "$f"; done |
  xargs -0 python myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title seems to imply that you can modify the script. In that case, use the `nargs` (number of args) option to allow more arguments for the `-f` flag:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--files', '-f', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.files)
```

Then you can use your find command easily:

```
15:44 $ find . -depth 1 | xargs python args.py -f
['./args.py', './for_clint', './install.sh', './sys_user.json']
```

Otherwise, if you can't modify the script, see @CharlesDuffy's answer.

Comment: You can't safely use `xargs` that way -- if you have more arguments than will fit on a single command line, you have no knowing if it'll split after a filename or after a `-f`. (Also, it's unsafe with filenames containing spaces, literal quotes, literal backslashes, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I just realized that. Think I should edit it with those caveats or remove the second part?

Comment: Personally, I'd lean against showcasing an unsafe practice if a safe alternative is available.